# Feed not appearing correctly

Tags: bug, android-app

Im in the feed tab and it seems like the columns don't have the enought width making it completly unreadable
Please fix it asap

My tablet is a BQ Edison 3

- App Version: 1.0.89[image]
- Device Manufacturer: bq
- Device Model: Edison 3

  - OS Version: 5.0 (1449647458)

Comment: It's a long time bug. Friendly tip: don't hold your breath, android app bugs are not fixed any more. (There's nobody to fix them.)